# An *actual*, relativistic, intuitive explanation for inductance…?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I searched high and low, and as far as I can tell, after years, there is not a *single* video or site that *actually* explains inductance in an intuitive way.

I mean an *actual* explanation. *Not* “Faraday’s law states …” or similar mere statements.

I mean an explanation based on the actual relativistic effects. On a level where it is acknowledged that there is no such thing as magnetic fields, and it is simply electrostatic fields (and spin) under relativistic effects. (For reference, this is the level of knowledge I am at: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu7cY2CPiRjVY-VaUZ69bXHZr5QslKbzo, which I consider almost an acceptable explanation, but could be improved with more Feynman-style understanding and less formula dropping. I also read the original paper on special relativity, but I can’t apply either to how electrons influence other electrons and protons in a coil.)

And I also mean an *intuitive* explanation. Preferably a visual one.
So no dumping of formulas with single letter identifiers and obscure symbols or such obfuscations please. But actual explanations of the *concepts* in a concise Feynman-style form.

In other words: I want to *understand* it. Intuitively and naturally. So much that I can consider it ”simple”.
I absolutely will not just rote memorize rules like an idiot. Nobody should.

**This would be of great value, as it would literally be the *only* explanation on the entire Internet, as far as I can tell.**

Comment: “On a level where it is acknowledged that there is no such thing as magnetic fields, and it is simply electrostatic fields (and spin) under relativistic effects.” This is a false statement, so it is not surprising that you have found no explanation of induction based on it

Comment: Well it's just special case of radiation. Radiation is deformation of electric field-lines.

Answer (score 12):

To echo Dale’s comment, the idea that the magnetic field doesn’t exist is an extremely common misconception for some reason. What relativity tells us is that electric fields and magnetic fields *mix together* under boosts, so a splitting of the electromagnetic field into electric and magnetic parts is frame-dependent.

The fact that $B^2-E^2$ (in Gaussian units) is a relativistic invariant should be proof enough of this fact; if there is any frame in which $B>E$, then there is no frame in which $B$ vanishes.

Ultimately there *is* no more fundamental explanation than one which refers to Faraday’s law, because Faraday’s law is one of the fundamental laws governing electromagnetism. Any other explanation necessarily reduces to “because that’s what Faraday’s law says” if you keep asking “why”.

Your repeated references to Feynman suggest that you think he would be capable of explaining induction without resorting to Faraday’s law or other fundamental equations. As a counterpoint, you might consider referring to the [lecture given by Feynman himself on this very topic](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_17.html).

Answer (score -1):

Actually I sympathize with you on this. The force between two current-carrying parallel wires is indeed explained very easily without resorting on magnetism, but only using the length contraction calculated by special relativity. Here you can derive the EXACT result given by the old definition of force and current. Similarly one should be able to do this with induction. And indeed you can it seems. But the picture is more complex because now you have to deal with charges that have an acceleration. The energy stored in a capacitor, I would say, is not stored in the electric field at all, it is stored in the immense force of attraction that is felt between the opposite plates. Thus there is a compression in the material (that's why you can't have liquid or gas as separators). You couldn't put the same amount of charge in opposite plates because this would result in a explosion. For example 1 coulomb charge put onto two plates of 1 m2 and 1 meter apart could support the weight of a few houses! But where exactly is the energy in a magnetic field? What happens to the materials of the inductor unit? Well, I agree with you, this is not something that people seem to mention, or even wonder about - but something must be happening. So I point you towards an revamp of an analysis carried out in the 1960s by Edward M. Purcell, which only deals with electrostatic forces when applied to accelerating frames of reference - https://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/mrr/MRRnotes.pdf.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).